# Make tex4ebook support memoir's \book

Tags: tex4ht, tex4ebook

Running `tex4ebook` on the following example

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}

Some dedication text

\book{Hello}

\part{World}

\chapter{How are you}

\end{document}
```

produces an `.epub` where the `\book` is formatted as a `likeSection`, but without any prior page breaks nor any corresponding bookmarks.

What configurations are needed for `tex4ebook` (or `tex4ht`) to support `memoir`'s `\book` construct, or would this require more extensive changes upstream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no support for the `\book` command in `tex4ht`, so what you see is just the formatting based on the fonts used by this command. Try the following configuration code that redefines it as a sectioning command recognized by `tex4ht`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\NewSection\book{\thebook}
\Configure{book}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<h2 class="bookHead"><span class="booknumber">}\bookname\refstepcounter{book}\space\thebook\HtmlParOff\HCode{</span><span class="booktitle">}}{\HCode{</span></h2>}\HtmlParOn}{}{}
\Css{.booknumber{display:block;}}
\Configure{toToc}{book}{part}
\CutAt{book}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The `\NewSection` command redefines `\book` as sectioning command recognized by `tex4ht`. The second argument should contain the counter command used to print the section number.

It is then necessary to configure the HTML code using `\Configure{book}`. This configuration is declared by `\NewSection`. It is a bit complicated, so I will try to describe it in more detail:

```
 {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<h2 class="bookHead"><span class="booknumber">}\bookname\refstepcounter{book}\space\thebook\HtmlParOff\HCode{</span><span class="booktitle">}}
```

The `\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP` closes the current paragraph, this code is necessary for all block level elements in `tex4ht`. The `\HCode{<h2 class="bookHead"><span class="booknumber">}` starts the HTML code, the `span.booknumber` element is used to style the book number, as it should stay on a separate line than the book title. `\bookname` is Memoir's command that contains the `Book` string. We need to manually increment the `book` counter using `\refstepcounter` command. `\HtmlParOff` disables HTML paragraphs, because some spurious paragraphs were produced in my tests. The `\HCode{</span><span class="booktitle">}` closes the book number  and opens `span.booktitle` for the book title.

```
{\HCode{</span></h2>}\HtmlParOn}
```

This code just closes all opened HTML elements and enables paragraphs.

```
\Css{.booknumber{display:block;}}
```

This command style the book number, it is just printed on a separate line.

```
 \Configure{toToc}{book}{part}
```

Requires `\book` to be included in TOC, on a same level as `\part`. I am not sure if it is possible to put it on a higher level without need to redefine lot of stuff.

```
 \CutAt{book}
```

This will open a new HTML page for each book.

This is the result in `ebook-viewer`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the very clear explanation! This certainly works for me, and happy enough to have the \book and \part bookmarks on the same level.